# Vuejs: How to set props value in async import loading?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs3

I am trying to set a loading component for my imported async component.
This works, but I would to change the 'color' props of this component before mounting it.
How can I achieve that ?

```
<script>
import loaderEllipsis from '@/components/common/loaderEllipsis.vue'
import SettingsNavigation from '@/components/views/Settings/SettingsNavigation.vue'

export default {
        name: 'view_settings',
        components: {

            loaderEllipsis,
            SettingsNavigation,
            SettingsOverview: function(){
                return {
                loading: loaderEllipsis, //<-- I want to change the color props here before mount it.
                component: new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        resolve(import(/* webpackChunkName: "settings-overview" */ '@/components/views/Settings/SettingsOverview.vue') );
                    }, 15000);
                }),

                }
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

I tried to change to props color by anyway and that doesn't work.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I founded the solution.

```
<script>
import loaderEllipsis from '@/components/common/loaderEllipsis.vue'
import SettingsNavigation from '@/components/views/Settings/SettingsNavigation.vue'

export default {
        name: 'view_settings',
        components: {

            loaderEllipsis,
            SettingsNavigation,
            SettingsOverview: function(){
                return {
               loading: {
                    render: function(createElement) {
                        return createElement(loaderEllipsis, {
                            props: {
                                color: 'red'
                            }  
                        })
                    }

                },
                component: new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        resolve(import(/* webpackChunkName: "settings-overview" */ '@/components/views/Settings/SettingsOverview.vue') );
                    }, 15000);
                }),

                }
            }
        }
}
</script>
```